# encode JSON in FBJS

Tags: json, facebook, fbml

I'm trying to encode a JS object into a JSON string (to read into a SWF as a FlashVar) but the encoders all seem to error out due to facebook prefixing the names of all JS objects with the app ID. I am not a very good JS debugger but the errors are telling me objects are not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but... AMF would be a bit much in this case as well as it's only a few vars. Upon further investigation it appears it's the 'instanceof' checking of the encoder I'm using that's causing the error.

"object":function(o){return o instanceof o.constructor?o.constructor:null},

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about AMF? Instead of sending through flashvar, get flash to call for the data.

If that fails, try working under an iframe.

If I had more details I could help a bit more.